# Not getting some header values in Angular 4

Tags: angular, cors, angular2-http

I am querying back-end like following with angular 4

```
    this.classzService.query({
      page: this.page,
      size: this.itemsPerPage,
      sort: this.sort(),
      url: url
    }).subscribe(
      (res: Response) => this.onQuerySuccess(res.json(), res.headers),
      (res: Response) => this.onError(res.json())
      );

    private onQuerySuccess(data, headers: Headers) {
       this.links = this.parseLinks.parse(headers.get('Link'));
       this.totalItems = headers.get('X-Total-Count');        
    }
```

Issue is `headers.get('Link')` and `headers.get('X-Total-Count')` gives me Null values.

When I check my chrome browser I see those values are there. What can be the issue.
[image]

Comment: Can you update the post with the `ClasszService` code

Comment: @Aravind Updated the ClasszService code. I am getting a response as expected. It just the angular Headers object dont contain my variables where as chrome shows my variables.

Comment: can you update the post with `options` values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This generally occurs in case of CORS when the origins are different. When you enable CORS at your server, by default it only exposes some default headers. In your case as you have two custom headers `Link` and `X-Total-Count`. So at your server you need to explicitly expose these headers using `Access-Control-Expose-Headers`. If you are using ASP.NET WebApi then you can do by adding this to your `WebApiConfig` class:

```
config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE", "Link, X-Total-Count"));
```

You can check this concept [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers) and [here](https://www.import.io/post/exposing-headers-over-cors-with-access-control-expose-headers/).